Issue with typescript compiler not recognising my vitest extended matchers
I have a typescript project where I have some unit tests that use extending matchers from vitest. The test are running fine, but if I run lint I keep getting errors like this one:

src/utils/tests/dateFilterUtils.test.ts:75:9 - error TS2339: Property 'toHaveMessage' does not exist on type 'Assertion<DateInputErrorI, any>'.

This is the file where I have my customMatcher
export const addCustomMatchers = (): void => {
  expect.extend({

    /**
     * Accepts an object with a message property and passes if the message is a non-empty string.
     */
    toHaveMessage(received: { message: string }) {
      return {
        pass: typeof received?.message === 'string' && received?.message?.length > 0,
        message: () =>
          this.utils.matcherHint('toHaveMessage', undefined, '', {
            isNot: this.isNot,
          } as any) + 
          '\n\n' +
          `Received: ${this.utils.printReceived(received)}`,
      };
    },

  });
};

I added a vitest.d.ts file the documentation mentions that looks like this
interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toHaveMessage: () => R;
}

declare module 'vitest' {
  type Assertion<T = any> = CustomMatchers<T>;  
  interface AsymmetricMatchersContaining extends CustomMatchers {}
}

I have also referenced the vitest.d.ts on the files section of my tsconfig.json file.
As I mentioned before the unit tests are running fine, but I do get the error when executing the typescript compiler
EDIT: Here is the code of dateFilterUtils.test.ts
import { addHours, startOfToday, subHours } from 'date-fns';
import { useDateInputFields, validateDateInputFields } from '../dateFilterUtils';
import { describe, test, expect } from 'vitest';

const getMockDateInputFieldsValue = (date: Date): ReturnType<typeof useDateInputFields> => {
  return {
    fullDate: date,
    year: date.getFullYear().toString(),
    month: (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
    day: date.getDate().toString(),
    time: `${date.getHours().toString()}:${date.getMinutes().toString()}`,
  } as ReturnType<typeof useDateInputFields>;
};

describe('dateFilterUtils', () => {
  describe('validateDateInputFields', () => {
    // Mock date input fields values for use in tests
    const empty = {
      fullDate: null,
      year: '',
      month: '',
      day: '',
      time: '',
    } as ReturnType<typeof useDateInputFields>;
    const future = getMockDateInputFieldsValue(new Date(2999, 2, 21, 12));
    const today = getMockDateInputFieldsValue(addHours(startOfToday(), 2)); // Note: assumes tests will not be run between 00:00 and 02:00
    const yesterday = getMockDateInputFieldsValue(subHours(startOfToday(), 2));
    const past = getMockDateInputFieldsValue(new Date(2007, 2, 21, 12));

    test('returns error if date is not valid', () => {
      expect(validateDateInputFields(empty)).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(past)).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields({ ...past, fullDate: null })).toHaveMessage();
    });

    test('returns error if date should be before the start of the current day', () => {
      expect(validateDateInputFields(future)).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(future, { mustBeBeforeStartOfToday: true })).toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(today, { mustBeBeforeStartOfToday: true })).toHaveMessage();
      expect(
        validateDateInputFields(yesterday, { mustBeBeforeStartOfToday: true })
      ).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeBeforeStartOfToday: true })).not.toHaveMessage();
    });

    test('returns error if date should be after the start of the current day', () => {
      expect(validateDateInputFields(yesterday)).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(future, { mustBeTodayOrInFuture: true })).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(today, { mustBeTodayOrInFuture: true })).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(yesterday, { mustBeTodayOrInFuture: true })).toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeTodayOrInFuture: true })).toHaveMessage();
    });

    test('returns error if date should be in the future', () => {
      expect(validateDateInputFields(past)).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(future, { mustBeInFuture: true })).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(today, { mustBeInFuture: true })).toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(yesterday, { mustBeInFuture: true })).toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeInFuture: true })).toHaveMessage();
    });

    test('returns error if date should be equal or after start date', () => {
      expect(
        validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeAfterDate: new Date(1900, 0) })
      ).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeAfterDate: new Date(2999, 0) })).toHaveMessage();
    });

    test('returns error if date should be after start date', () => {
      expect(
        validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeEqualOrAfterDate: new Date(2007, 2, 21, 12) })
      ).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(
        validateDateInputFields(past, { mustBeEqualOrAfterDate: new Date(2999, 0) })
      ).toHaveMessage();
    });

    test('returns error if time is not optional and time empty', () => {
      const date = getMockDateInputFieldsValue(new Date(2999, 2, 21));
      date.time = '';
      expect(validateDateInputFields(date, { isTimeOptional: true })).not.toHaveMessage();
      expect(validateDateInputFields(date, { isTimeOptional: false })).toHaveMessage();
    });
  });
});


This is not an ESLint error - it comes from the Typescript compiler. Identifiable by the "TS"-Prefix. So the problem is in "src/utils/tests/dateFilterUtils.test.ts"; which you didn't share in your question.

Thanks, I updated the question to include that file

Using this  in vitest.d.ts solved the issue
import { Assertion } from 'vitest';

declare module 'vitest' {
  export interface Assertion {
    toHaveMessage(expectedMessage?: string): Assertion;
  }
}


In the vitest.d.ts file your're defining the property toBeNullOrUndefined, but your CustomMatcher defines toHaveMessage.
So change it to
interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toHaveMessage: () => R;
}


Sorry that was a typo when trying to reduce the file to only include one of the extend matchers that I was using. I have changed that to toHaveMessage and I am still getting the same error

It looks like using this as my vitest.d.ts has worked:
import { Assertion } from 'vitest';
declare module 'vitest' {
export interface Assertion {
toHaveMessage(expectedMessage?: string): Assertion;
}
}
